# Update an element of a list, where list is a value in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, key-value

When I'm trying to update an element of a list, where list is a value in dictionary, it updates all values at that index in every list in the dictionary.

Sample code:

```
dit = {}
d = {}
ls = ['hhh','ew']
a = "hhh"
b = "ew"
j = 3
dit[a] = [1,2,3,4]
dit[b] = [5,6,7,8]
const = [0,2,3,4]
d = dict.fromkeys(dit.keys() ,const)
print(d)
for i in ls:
    print(i)
    d[i][0] = max(d[i][0], j) 
    print(d)
    j += 1
```

OUTPUT I'm getting is:

```
{'hhh': [0, 2, 3, 4], 'ew': [0, 2, 3, 4]}
hhh
{'hhh': [3, 2, 3, 4], 'ew': [3, 2, 3, 4]}
ew
{'hhh': [4, 2, 3, 4], 'ew': [4, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Output required is:

```
{'hhh': [0, 2, 3, 4], 'ew': [0, 2, 3, 4]}
hhh
{'hhh': [3, 2, 3, 4], 'ew': [0, 2, 3, 4]}
ew
{'hhh': [3, 2, 3, 4], 'ew': [4, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you assign the const itself on each dict element. When you update this list, it will update all of its occurences. Change this in your code and it will work:

```
d = dict.fromkeys(dit.keys() ,const)
```

to

```
d = {i:const.copy() for i in dit.keys()}
```

Comment: I changed it, try again please. Probably it was the same logic (it just used a const.copy() for all keys and updated them alltogether)

Comment: Yes your original version had a variant on the original problem. The new version would now work.